# Why do I need to create an array many times?

Tags: java

This programm shuffles a source list by pairs. So that original list

> "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"

trasfoms to

> 11^12 19^20 17^18 15^16 1^2 5^6 3^4 13^14 7^8 9^10

The above is true while commented line is uncommented. Now, if **line A** is commented then all the elements in shuffleList are `19^20`.

```
public class ShuffleService {

public static void shuffleList(List<String> list) {

    System.out.println(list);

    ArrayList<String[]> shuffleList = new ArrayList<String[]>(10);
    String[] arr = new String[2];
    boolean flag = false;
    int step = 0;

    for(String s: list){

        if(flag){
            arr[1]=s;
        } else {
            arr[0]=s;
        }

        flag=!flag;
        step++;

        if(step==2){
            shuffleList.add(arr);
            step=0;
            //arr = new String[2]; //**line A**
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(shuffleList);

    for(String[] val: shuffleList){
        System.out.print(val[0]);
        System.out.print("^");
        System.out.println(val[1]);
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"};
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(a);
        shuffleList(list1);
    }
}
```

So why do I need to uncomment **line A** in the program to work properly?

Comment: Because otherwise you are modifying the values of one object (a singular array) by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you rewrite the values to `arr` (without remaking it), you're also going to modify the values already in the list.

Adding an object to the list doesn't stop you from modifying it, it will not make copies on its own. By calling `new String[2]` in your loop you're effectively building a new string array for each pair that you add to the list, which is what you want.